# JFrame.revalidate() and producing a grey screen - Confusion

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint, java-2d

I have a method in a `JPanel`

```
private void paintScore(Graphics2D g) {
    Font scoreFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 72);
    g.setFont(scoreFont);
    FontMetrics scoreFontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
    g.drawString("" + playerOneScore, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - 30
            - scoreFontMetrics.stringWidth("" + playerOneScore),
            SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);
    g.drawString("" + playerTwoScore, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 + 30,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);

}
```

When I call this method, the very first time it appears to work. Then, after that it never works again.

If I comment out the invocation of the method, it consistently works.

However, If I call `JFrame's revalidate()` methods, the program also consistently works.

I am not sure what is going on here.

I can post full source code if required.

Thanks in Advance

---

Here is the rest of the code.

Main JPanel extended class.

```
       import java.awt.Color;
       import java.awt.Font;
       import java.awt.FontMetrics;
       import java.awt.Graphics;
       import java.awt.Graphics2D; 
       import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
       import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
       import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

       import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import javax.swing.JPanel;

     public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, MouseMotionListener {

private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
private static final int INDENT = 20;

private int playerOneScore = 0;
private int playerTwoScore = 0;
private ImageEntity playerOne = new ImageEntity("Images/bouncer.bmp");
private ImageEntity playerTwo = new ImageEntity("Images/bouncer.bmp");

private int mouseX = 0;
private int mouseY = 0;

private BufferedImage gameScreen = new BufferedImage(SCREEN_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics2D gameScreenGraphics = gameScreen.createGraphics();

public GamePanel() throws Exception {
    paintBackground(gameScreenGraphics);
    paintScore(gameScreenGraphics);
    paintBouncers(gameScreenGraphics);

}

public void run() {
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m) {
    mouseX = m.getXOnScreen();
    mouseY = m.getYOnScreen();
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent m) {
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(gameScreen, 0, 0, this);
}

private void paintBackground(Graphics2D g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        g.fillRect(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - 5, i * SCREEN_HEIGHT / 10, 10,
                (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 10) - 10);
    }
}

private void paintScore(Graphics2D g) {
    Font scoreFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 72);
    g.setFont(scoreFont);
    FontMetrics scoreFontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
    g.drawString("" + playerOneScore, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - 30
            - scoreFontMetrics.stringWidth("" + playerOneScore),
            SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);
    g.drawString("" + playerTwoScore, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 + 30,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);

}

private void paintBouncers(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawImage(playerOne.getImage(), playerOne.getX(), playerOne.getY(),
            this);
    g.drawImage(playerTwo.getImage(), playerTwo.getX(), playerTwo.getY(),
            this);
}

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    JFrame mainPane = new JFrame("Pong - Mrinank Sharma");
    mainPane.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    mainPane.setVisible(true);
    mainPane.setResizable(false);
    GamePanel gp = new GamePanel();
    mainPane.add(gp);
    mainPane.revalidate();
}

  }
```

ImageEntity is a class which simply is a wrapper for BufferedImage.

Thanks again guys

Comment: It doesn't appear to me that your problem is in the code you've posted. How are you calling this method? Where does the Graphics2D object used here come from? Can you provide more information and code including the JPanel's paintComponent method (or paint if you override that)?

Comment: you can to use revalidate for remove and then add new JPanel to the JFrame, for better help sooner post an SSCCE

Comment: @brano: I'm not sure that we want to see it all as it could be a large program with most of the code unrelated to the problem at hand. Much better would be to have the original poster create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) (as suggested by mKorbel), a *very small* compilable and runnable program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels My mistake, sorry.

Comment: It isn't much - a small pong game that I'm trying to make.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code is producing a gray screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218098/code-is-producing-a-gray-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
public GamePanel() {
    paintBackground(gameScreenGraphics);
    paintScore(gameScreenGraphics);
    paintBouncers(gameScreenGraphics);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    repaint();
}
```

You forgot to add mouse motion listener, and to repaint panel. revalidate(); has no use in this case.